# gdb : Adding a breakpoint and rerun using existing coredump

Tags: c++, gdb

my task crashed on production server, and I downloaded the binary and the core dump. I then run :

```
gdb task coredump
```

And I can do some basic debugging in gdb including `bt, frame, info locals` etc. I have identified a variable that it's content look weird to me. Assuming I am in here :

```
(gdb) frame 8
....
(gdb) list
...
(gdb) print d_variable
....
```

I now want to go a few lines up, and inspect d_variable and how it got populated or at what point the value isn't correct. I can add a break point and run my task, but this as far as I can tell, it doesn't use the existing coredump and I cannot reproduce the error.

The question is, can I run the same coredump, with breakpoints this time so I can inspect how this "abnormal" value occurred?

I am not very experienced with gdb so hope the above makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can I run the same coredump, with breakpoints this time so I can inspect how this "abnormal" value occurred?

No.

In order to achieve what you want, you need need to record the crash under a *reversible* debugger, such as [rr](https://rr-project.org/).

Since you haven't done so, your only option is to *guess* where the variable became corrupt, add logging and hope that the future crash will provide more info.

Before doing that, I suggest:

- instrumenting all your unit tests (you do have unit tests, right?) with `-fsanitize=address` (assuming your platform is supported) and making sure they are [AddressSanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer)-clean.
- instrumenting the actual server with AddressSanitizer and running it though load-test.

There is a high chance that doing above steps will reveal one or more bugs.